# What is the suggested callback style for Node.js libraries?

Tags: node.js

With focus on how errors are handled:

- There's the style that `fs` promotes: One callback where the first argument is an error (if any), and the remaining are response values.
- The core library confusingly doesn't always pass an error to the first argument of a callback.  `http.get`, for example.
- Another style is to have two callbacks (callback & errback).  Promoted by http://howtonode.org/control-flow-part-ii

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will certainly say that in most cases, you will see the following signature for callbacks.

```
function (err, result)
```

This is pretty much standard today.

But it also depends on what you need to "return" like in the createServer example where two objects are passed back to the callback.

```
createServer(function (req, res) {
});
```

This is mostly the exception and in most libraries you will see the first form.