# How does this memoize function work?

Tags: javascript

I am feeling very stupid today.
I keep looking at this code, trying to trace it, but I just cannot figure out:

1. What it's actually meant to do
2. How it works

As far as I can see, the very first time it's called it's the only time `action` is the same as `callFn`. So, the very first time it's run, it creates the stack array. Then I lose it. Action is assigned a function that just adds the passed callback to the stack. Then fn is *actually* called and based on its result, "action" is set to either callFn (?!?) or to a function that calls the callback... And then, all the calls in the stack are called.

I hate getting lost in code, but this is a little beyond me. Anybody smarter than me able to "get it"?

```
var memoize = function(fn) {
    var callFn = function(callback) {
        var stack = [callback];

        action = function(callback) {
            stack.push(callback);
        };

        fn(function(err, val) {
            action = err ? callFn : function(callback) {
                callback(null, val);
            };

            while (stack.length) stack.shift()(err, val);
        });
    };

    var action = callFn;

    return function(callback) {
        action(callback);
    };
};
```

Comment: That's a bit cryptic.  For reference here is a much easier to read version of a memoize function form underscore.js: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-60

Comment: Do you have an example of how you see it being used?

Comment: Where did you get the function from?

Comment: This function is from https://github.com/gett/mongojs -- now that I understand it, I think it's fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not only memoize the result of `fn`, it also ensured that there is only one active call to `fn` at a time. Every `callback` that is provided during an active call (when `action` is that anon function from line 5) is pushed on the stack, and once `fn` calls back the stack (it's a queue actually) is processed and the result is published to all callbacks.

The confusing "*`action` is set to either `callFn` or…*" happens based on the `err` condition. This parameter [indicates that an error happened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13965174/1048572) and is  falsy otherwise. So when `fn` calls back with an error, the stack is processed as usual but also the `action` is **reset** to the original `callFn` (you remember, it had that value at the beginning as well) so subsequent calls will **retry** to get a value from `fn`. If there was no error, the `action` is just set to a function that always calls back with the result `val` that came back once.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh that makes so much sense! It's a function from https://github.com/gett/mongojs -- is this a common pattern, with the "queue" etc.? Reading it now, it really does look immensely smart and neat. Don't you think? Thanks a BILLION for explaining it...

Comment: Yes, it's smart. Yet I fear smartness is not too common... Most libraries (mongojs, jQuery.Callback) have abstraction functions for this so you don't have to handle the queues yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Memoization is a technique that uses side-effects to improve -at runtime- the performance of a function without altering its behavior. Roughly speaking, you can do memoization by storing function values that were returned in previous calls, and returning these values in further calls to the function instead of actually calling the function.

[Read more](http://philogb.github.com/blog/2008/09/05/memoization-in-javascript/)